# How to get left aligned tabs with background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the active color (after its clicked it remains twitter's light-blue color) for each tab:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills padding-12 tab-color-blue background-blue">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Sample</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Sample</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

But I need the tabs to be left aligned.

if I include `<div class="tabbable tabs-left">`, it's not working.

I need left aligned tabs with tab-color.

Comment: where is your js code ?

Comment: and your css? A jsfiddle would be really handy.

Comment: i have no js and css file for this

Comment: how do you add colors with no css?

Comment: @chadocat if i use<ul class="nav nav-pills padding-12 tab-color-blue background-blue">, whenever i select a tab  it automatically change the tab color . but i need left aligned tab.